# newby with pine-script trying to get multi conditional color to plot on histogram and convert to v4

Tags: pine-script

more importantly i'm trying to understand why i can't convert this color definition to v4 - every way i try it errors out "mismatched input '?' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'"

```
plotColor = hist[0] > 0 
    ? hist[0] > hist[1] ? lime : green 
    : hist[0] < hist[1] ? maroon : red
plot(hist[0], style = columns, color = plotColor, linewidth = 3)
```

just not getting the syntax for multi-conditional, conditional... read about tabs and spaces and the like and i tried it with bracketed conditions as well still couldn't get it to add to chart if there was any pinescript version identifier on the indicator - funny thing is, though, that if i remove a pinescript version identifier it will plot on the chart but then i can't convert it to v4...
thanks,
w

Answer (score 0):

Do you converting it manually? If so,

```
plotColor = hist[0] > 0 
     ? hist[0] > hist[1] ? color.lime : color.green 
     : hist[0] < hist[1] ? color.maroon : color.red
    
plot(hist[0], style = plot.style_columns, color = plotColor, linewidth = 3)
```

When splitting it onto the following line, the continuation of the statement must start with more than one indentation (not equal to multiple of 4 spaces) [user manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html#line-wrapping)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out... the line-wrap thing is a little odd but here's what i did in case anyone else finds this ...
original code above with a tab in front of each indented line was changed to remove the tabs and add 2 spaces at the beginning of the 2nd line of the plotColor definition and string the 3rd line behind the second all on one line...

```
plotColor = hist > 0
  ? hist[0] > hist[1] ? color.lime : color.green : hist[0] < hist[1] ? color.maroon : color.red

plot(hist[0], style=plot.style_histogram, color=plotColor, linewidth=3)
```

it converted to v4pine with no problem and now links to a host divergence indicator properly...

when it was converted to v4 it came out with 3 spaces in front of the wrapped line...